# Saving Options Clicked in a Table to a Form or Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code where you choose between 10 radio buttons labeled with the numbers 1-10 in 5 different table cells and then in the 6th cell it shows the total of the numbers selected once all 5 radio buttons have been selected. What I am now wondering is if there is a way to, in the click of a button, in any language compatible with HTML, to save the whole table to a form of some kind, with the values of the 6th row, and if that can be done, is it possible to, after the button has been clicked on 6 different times with different 6th row values, it makes another form with the average of all 6 forms that have been submitted? I am perfectly fine if it saves the values to a Excel spreadsheet as well.
Anyways, here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
      row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align=center>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Team Play</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this one;**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
      row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});


function getPostData(){
  var data =[];
  
  $("tr.item").each(function(ind,tag){
    var row = {"dataid":$(tag).attr("data-id"), "selects" : [], "overall":0};
    
    $(tag).find("input:checked").each(function(i,td){
      
      if($(td).val()!=null) {
          var item={};
      
          $(item).attr( $(td).attr("name") , $(td).val() );
      
          row.selects.push(item);
        }
      
    });
    
    if(row.selects.length>0){
      row.overall = $(tag).find(".overall").html();
      
      if(row.overall!="") data.push(row);
    }
    
  });
  
  
  if(data.length==0)
     console.log("There is no any selected value!");
  else
     console.log(data);
  }
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="getPostData()">Collect data</button>
<table align=center>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Team Play</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td class="overall"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
      </td>
      <td class="overall"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wait so what happens when you click 'Collect data'? Nothing visible is happening.

Comment: when selection comlete the overall score will show. After you see over all score click the Collect Data button and look at the console. You will see Json data. You can post it where ever you want.

Comment: Even though I can see it in the snippet when I paste the code into my own nothing happens.

Comment: It also appears it can only collect 1 row at a time.

Comment: At least in the snippet, still not working with my own code.